# OCaml Test if a string is almost empty or contains keywords

Tags: string, algorithm, ocaml, keyword

I've got a problem in OCaml, I'm currently learning it but I'm quite a newbie still. I would like to make a function which is returning true if the string is empty or contains only whitespace and in the same time remove any occurence of `begin` and `end`.

I tried already this:

```
let isEmptyString s =  
  let rec empty i =
    if i < 0 then true
    else
          let c = String.get s i in
          if c = ' ' || c = '\009' then empty (pred i)
          else false
  in
  s = Str.global_replace( Str.regexp "begin") "" s;
  s = Str.global_replace( Str.regexp "end") "" s;
  empty (pred (String.length s))
```

But obviously, this function is not working as I would like it because I obtain still `begin` in `Formula.importNrAgentsFormula` after calling it... Here is my way to call it :

```
while true do
   let input = read_line () in
   if not (isEmptyString input) then
      let (nr, f) = Formula.importNrAgentsFormula input in
      incr counter;
      flush stdout;
      match choice with
       | "graph" -> printRes (Graph.isSat ~verbose:verb nr f)
       | _ -> printUsage ()
   else ()
done
```

If someone with more experiences in OCaml could spot and explain to me the error, I would be glad :)

Thanks in advance,

Best Regards.

Comment: Julien's answer is fine but I would add something. The way you do it, you will read your string twice but you could it only once by writing `Str.global_replace( Str.regexp "\\(begin\\)\\|\\(end\\)") "" s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you let your function `isEmptyString` (`isBlankString` rather?) do what it is supposed to do (just check if it contains only whitespaces or nothing), it should not modify the original string. You can do this in your loop:

```
while true do
   let input = read_line () in
   let input = Str.global_replace( Str.regexp "begin") "" input in
   let input = Str.global_replace( Str.regexp "end") "" input in
   if not (isEmptyString input) then
   ...
```

**Edit**: Sorry for the late edit, here is some additional information on your error:

If you run your function in OCaml, you will see this warning:

```
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
```

on the line of `s = Str.global_replace( Str.regexp "begin") "" s;`. That is because the `=` operator in OCaml is not the assignment operator in this case but the equality operator, so on this line you simply compare your two values and return a boolean. Since OCaml expects `e1` in `e1;e2` to return `unit`, you get this warning.

In OCaml, values of variables are *immutable*, so you can:

- Use another variable as @Jason suggests: `let t = Str.global_replace( Str.regexp "begin") "" s`
- "shadow" the old value as I suggest above: `let s = Str.global_replace( Str.regexp "begin") "" s`
- Use a reference (a pointer to a location in memory): `let s = ref "before" in s := "after"`, you can then access the value pointed by the reference with the `!`operator: `!s`. However, if you are learning functional programming, I suggest you try not to use any imperative features of OCaml at the beginning to discover this new paradigm and its possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

As I am at work I don't have utop with me, but just from first glance, in your first one, the documentation says:

```
val global_replace : regexp -> string -> string -> string
```

That means you don't need a ";" as that is for when functions return unit and is syntactic sugar for something like

```
let () = print_endline("foobar")
```

Additionally, you need to use a let statement as you cannot just reassign the value of s. I don't recommend shadowing the variable as that's generally bad practice in functional programming. Use something like:

```
    let t = (Str.global_replace( Str.regexp "begin") "" s)
```

Also, your function does two different things. The helper recursive function you wrote returns true and false which is good (I'm assuming it works). What you ultimately use it for however is what you're returning. Therefore, for the first function are you aren't really returning the string if "begin" and "end"s have been replaced. Therefore you should have the end output of your function actually a tuple of type (bool,string). Then you can match on it when you call it (e.g.

```
let b,s = isEmptyString "foobar" in
if not b then:
  rest of your code
```

I believe you have the right idea for your function though. 
Also in your second function is there a way for you to not use any while loops and counters? (Also hopefully your counter is implemented with references otherwise you won't have anything global). I would suggest retrying the place where you call your first function as loops and counters are core to imperative programming and not functional (which is what makes OCaml so

```
fun
```

:). If not, it's fine sometimes there are just things you can't really do in OCaml without using its imperative features. Let me know if those suggestions don't work.